# How can I rewrite the values of facets shown in the Current Search block?

Tags: search

I am using the Facet API for Solr search on my site.

The [Facet API Bonus](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) module provides a **Rewrite items** filter:

> Filter "Rewrite Items": Filter plugin to rewrite labels or other data
>   of the facet items by implementing a new dedicated
>   hook_facet_items_alter (in a structured array, before rendering). Very
>   handy to rewrite list field values or totally custom encoded facet
>   values for user friendly output.

My site has three facets for boolean fields that have "Yes" or "No" options by default.  Using this filter, I have rewritten them so that what is being selected is more clear:

```
function mymodule_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
  switch ($settings->facet) {
    case 'field_friends':
      foreach($build as $key => $item) {
        if($item['#indexed_value'] == '1') {
          $build[$key]['#markup'] = t("Wants friends");
        }
        else {
          $build[$key]['#markup'] = t("Doesn't want friends");
        }
      }
    break;
    case 'field_money':
      foreach($build as $key => $item) {
        if($item['#indexed_value'] == '1') {
          $build[$key]['#markup'] = t("Wants money");
        }
        else {
          $build[$key]['#markup'] = t("Doesn't want money");
        }
      }
```

This works for the facets.  But the problem is, if the user clicks **Wants friends** and **Doesn't want money**, then the Current Search block shows **Yes** and **No** (the unmodified facet values).

How can I rewrite the values of the facets show in the Current Search block too?  As it is now, if a user selects multiple **Yes** and **No** values, they will have no idea what is actually being applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is not available by default, but there is a [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2438059) to add this to Facet API.